# Implementing functions, ifs to get current location using navigator.location js&html

Tags: javascript, html

Hello trying to implement what I have learned in JavaScript so far into locating myself. Every time I run the HTML with the code the "else" part shows up. Which is weird because my browser supports this. Would appreciate any guidance and input. Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
function findMe() {
  var msg = document.getElementById('out');
  if (navigator.location) {
    navigator.location.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);

  function success(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    msg.innerHTML = latitude + longitude;
  }

  function fail(){
    msg.innerHTML = '<p>Something went wrong</p>';
  }

  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = '<p>Sorry your browser does not support this tech</p>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're going to want to use `navigator.geolocation` instead of both of your `navigator.location`'s to prompt the user to allow access to their current location! https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

UPDATE to include your code, edited

```
var msg = document.getElementById('out');

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);

  function success(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    msg.innerHTML = latitude + longitude;
  }

  function fail(){
    msg.innerHTML = '<p>Something went wrong</p>';
  }

} else {
  msg.innerHTML = '<p>Sorry your browser does not support this tech</p>';
}
```

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying; am I not having `code`navigator.location`code` to test if browser supports it and the next one I am using to get current location. What are both of my prompts?  Took a look at the url you sent, and using that script over there works. Just don't understand what is wrong with the code I wrote, tried putting the Success and Fail functions outside of the `code`findme()`code` but still does not work.

Comment: `navigator.location` is not the correct syntax to successfully get location, it should be: `if (navigator.geolocation)` and `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);`. If you change both instances from `.location` to `.geolocation`, it should work successfully

Comment: I just updated the original answer to include the fixed version of your code block. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No I see it!! Thank you marcx, means a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! I know it can be discouraging to get stuck! If everything worked out, go ahead and mark as answered!